# Gnuplot bar graph alignments

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have date and value in .dat file where I am trying to plot a graph. I have achieved plotting a bar graph, However the graph does not exactly fit into the borders

Data in ".dat" file

> 2016-04-21 12804662
>   2016-04-20 12294895
>   2016-04-19 12629974
>   2016-04-18 10775333
>   2016-04-17 10499770

Below is the gnupot script

```
/usr/bin/gnuplot <<\__EOF

set terminal pngcairo size 900, 300
set output "chart_1.png"
set grid
set tics font ", 10"
set boxwidth 10000
set style fill solid
set format y ""
set xtics rotate
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
plot "DATA.dat" using 1:2:xtic(1) with boxes notitle lc rgb "blue", "" u  1:2:2 with labels notitle offset char 0,1

__EOF
```

Below is the graph. Could someone help me in plotting this graph fit into the borders and look more sensible?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Any help on this request

Comment: Check out `set xrange` and `set yrange`.  I believe that setting the ranges is all that you need to do (add a little to both sides and some to the top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Resize your output `.png` a thinner one! (e.g. 500x300)
2. Use wider bars! (e.g. 50000)
3. Use `xrange/yrange` or

   ```
   plot [<xmin>:<xmax>][<ymin>:<ymax>]
   ```
4. Improve your solution 'self-automatic' with `GP_VAL`-s, like the code bellow:

   ```
   set terminal pngcairo size 500, 300
   set grid
   set tics font ", 10"
   set boxwidth 50000
   set style fill solid
   set format y ""
   set xtics rotate
   set xdata time
   set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d"
   set output "/dev/null"
   plot "DATA.dat" using 1:2:xtic(1) with boxes notitle lc rgb "blue", "" u 1:2:2 with labels notitle offset char 0,1
   plot[GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN-20000:GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX+20000][0:GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX*1.25] "DATA.dat" using 1:2:xtic(1) with boxes notitle lc rgb "blue", "" u 1:2:2 with labels notitle offset char 0,1
   set output "chart_1.png"
   plot[GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN-20000:GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX+20000][0:GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX*1.25] "DATA.dat" using 1:2:xtic(1) with boxes notitle lc rgb "blue", "" u 1:2:2 with labels notitle offset char 0,1
   # exit with exit or EOF or...
   ```

First two blank plot are necessary to initialize the values of `GPVAL_X_MIN` and others with the correct values from your data file (anytime they update *after plot*).

---

[image: My output]

---